# application.desktop

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop, autostart

I'm looking for a way to start an application on a particular display.  For instance if I want to start a firefox kiosk on two different heads or perhaps a firefox kiosk on one head and a Libre Office session on the other.  How do I force firefox to spawn on display 1 and libre office on display 2.  I know there is a way to do this but I can't remember how the .desktop files should be written, what variables are available.  Is there a good listing of thse environmental variables etc. that I can look at?  What language/format is this in?

Thanks,
JTK

Answer (score 0):

The utility `wmctrl` allows you some control on this. To launch an application on a different workspace, you may need to create a little wrapper script that 1) moves to a different workspace 2) launches your application then, optionally, 3) moves back to the initial workspace.

See `man wmctrl` for documention on the tool. the `-s` option switches desktops, so

```
wmctrl -s 1
```

will switch you to the second workspace (counting starts with 0).